# Boo string interpolation not working

Tags: string, interpolation, boo

I downloaded the latest build of Boo this morning, and I'm trying to get started with the language. One of the features I need for my use case is Boo's string interpolation. However, I haven't been able to get it to work at all.

Here's my test code (some of which was copied directly from the Boo website):

```
print System.DateTime.Now

title = "My Demo Site"
print title
print "$(title)"

print """
<html>
    <header> $title </header>
</html>
"""
name = "Santa Claus"
print "Hello, $name!"

now = "IMPORTANT"
print("Tomorrow will be $now")

print("""
----
Life, the Universe and Everything: $(len('answer to life the universe and everything')).
----
""")
```

and my output:

```
3/31/2015 10:25:37 AM
My Demo Site
$(title)

<html>
    <header> $title </header>
</html>

Hello, $name!
Tomorrow will be $now

----
Life, the Universe and Everything: $(len('answer to life the universe and everything')).
----
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version (0.9.4.9 as of this writing)?

Comment: Perhaps not. When I wen't back to look, I realized I had downloaded the Boo Explorer archive instead of the Boo release. Is there any way to tell which version of Boo I'm running in that?

Comment: That's the problem. Running the same script under booi.exe in v0.9.4.9 works as expected. Is Boo Explorer outdated/no longer supported, or is there a way to make it work with the latest version of Boo? @MauricioScheffer, if you want to make your commend an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: AFAICT Boo Explorer is ancient, I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: Yeah... that's what I was thinking also. Perhaps SharpDevelop is supposed to be the replacement...

Comment: Also try https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d15c62f-de0d-42f0-863a-daa8330d977a , I've used it a couple of years ago, it was pretty good.

Comment: You can probably get your boo version by running `booish` from a command line: it prints out the version number:  Mine prints `running Boo 0.9.4.9 on 4.0.0`